# Unknown cloumn 'labourname' in fieldlist in mysql C#

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, dataset-designer

i am currently working in C# windows application using Entity mysql database. while trying to preview value datatable in the in the *.xsd file i am getting **"Unknown Cloumn 'labourname' in fieldlist"** error dialog box.

But i run the Same query in the mysql i am getting the correct result.There i find the **labourname** column.

Pls anyone one tell me why i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

if you are comparing this column name in your C# code then make sure the strings are in same case on either side of comparison.

Comment: thanks for answering me. I compared the column name that are Correct in either sides.pls help me to solve this problem